# Is speaking without knowledge not about Islam still a sin? Is being biased haram?

Tags: halal-haram, behavior

I know speaking of Islam without knowlege is forbidden. But what about speaking without knowledge not involved with Islam?

Example: Many non Muslims write their own biased and personal definitions of people's names, type of people and other words in urbandictionary.com . Most of these words are sexist and made mostly by non Muslim Americans.

Another question, is being biased a sin? Lets say if you hate a group of people by one person and you give judgment, think, and act by your personal feelings?

Answer (score 2):

### All perfect praise be to Allah.

As of your first question,
 **what about speaking without knowledge not involved with Islam?**
If you are speaking about something without its knowledge, than in relaity what you are doing is wither telling a lie, or telling people what you THINK that thing might be or might not be. So at least it is lie and islam doesnot allow anyone to lie in any matter.

Quoting from [here](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=302476)

*Allaah says (what means): **{O you who have believed, if there comes to you a disobedient one with information, investigate, lest you harm a people out of ignorance and become, over what you have done, regretful.}** [Quran 49:6]

Abu Hurayrah  may  Allaah  be  pleased  with  him related that the Prophet  sallallaahu  `alayhi  wa  sallam ( may  Allaah exalt his mention ) said: “**Suffice it as a lie that one speaks about everything one hears.**” [Muslim]

Shaykh Al-Uthaymeen  may  Allaah  have  mercy  upon  him said in his commentary on this Hadeeth:

“It means that if a person speaks about everything he hears without verifying it, then he is likely to lie, and this is the reality. Some people come to you and say, such a thing has happened, and if you investigate the matter, you find that it did not happen. Or, a person comes to you and says, so and so said such and such, and if you investigate the matter, you find that he did not say it.”*

**Now about the example you gave**, it does not quite fits on question you asked, what i can say is if you want to know the meaning of a name, name is nothing but some word of some language. You must check that language for the word and its root. Such as my name is from arabic, if you need to know meaning of my name, you must be looking in some arabic dictionary for all the words i have in my name. Or better ask someone who knows arabic. And of-course whoever is doing such is wrong

### Now on your second question:

Allah says in quran:

> يا ايها الذين امنوا كونوا قوامين لله شهداء بالقسط ولا يجرمنكم شنان قوم
>   على الا تعدلوا اعدلوا هو اقرب للتقوى واتقوا الله ان الله خبير بما
>   تعملون

Quran 5/8

> O you who have believed, be persistently standing firm for Allah ,
>   witnesses in justice, and **do not let the hatred of a people prevent
>   you from being just. Be just; that is nearer to righteousness. And
>   fear Allah ; indeed, Allah is Acquainted with what you do.**

And there are hundreds of example on this topic, but the above ayah sums it all up. That you must NOT!

You can search on this topic and there is lot of examples from islamic history on this topic you may find books on this.

### Allah knows best.